# Initial migration source file does not contain schema for database

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-config, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework 6 with Web API. I have applied **Enable-Migrations** command in package manager console and Migration folder created with Configuration class.
I have executed **Add-Migration -InitialCreate**  command initial migration source file created but up and down methods are empty.

so when I recreate the database no table is created except migrationhistory table. No table is created into database so my API cannot perform any POST, GET operation and getting below error message.

> Exception type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   Message       : Invalid object name 'dbo.Template'.

Please assist me.

I have put my connection string in database.config in startup project not in Web.config of startup project reason behind this was I didn't want to start Web API when database name changes in Web.config. I have attached my Web.config snapshot.[image]

MigrationHistory Table [image]

Below is code for DBContext class.

```
public class TestDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SamlNode> SamlNodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }

    private static string connectionString
    {
        get
        {
            Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath);
            ConnectionStringsSection connectionString = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("database");

            if (connectionString != null && connectionString.ConnectionStrings["TestDBContext"] != null)
            {
                return connectionString.ConnectionStrings["TestDBContext"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }
    }

    public TestDBContext()
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TestDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TestDBContext>());
        //Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TestDBContext, Migrations.Configuration>(connectionString));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Regards,
Rashi

Comment: Can you show us your DbContext class?

Comment: @CodeNotFound, I have added my dbcontext class. Plz suggest now.

Comment: what's in your _MigrationHistory table?

Comment: @Morten Anderson , I have attached my _MigrationHistory table